# Pass current marker title to VC when marker is selected

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to pass the name of the selected location in another VC.
I'm trying to do this

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showInfo", sender: data)
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showInfo" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! InfoViewController

        destination.name = location.name
    }
}
```

"locations" is an array of all locations shown in my map.

My problem is that it always pass the first row of the "locations" instead of selected marker.

How can I get the current marker title? Thanks.

Comment: first you get string value in array than after pass the string value in another vc

Comment: Send us more code please?

Comment: I better rephrase the question: How can I get the current marker title?